# HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile mail merge - cannot change placeholders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've built an HTML file inside the Google Script code editor.
Inside the HTML I've included placeholders, such as {{NAME}}.
My goal is to replace these placeholders with data from a Google Sheet. 
Well...it's not working :)
The email is received with just HtmlOutput in the body.
Code below. What am I missing?

```
var emailBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('client_intro_email');
emailBody = emailBody.replace({{NAME}}, clientname);

GmailApp.sendEmail(clientemail, 'subject', '',
                     {htmlBody: emailBody.getContent(),
                      }
```

```
 Hi {{NAME}},
```

---

Here are the variables I'd like to push into the HTML. Content of the cells is text.

```
  var clientname = spreadsheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var clientemail = spreadsheet.getRange('P2').getValue();
```

Comment: You should read about scriplets and templated html.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have already read that article. It seems that the relevant part for me is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates). But I cannot understand how to make it happen. My idea was to obtain a set of variables (see updated question) and then push them into the HTML before sending it out as a personalized email to a new client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use templated HTML to dynamically insert HTML content from your script.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on scriptlets:

> Apps Script templates can contain three special tags, called scriptlets. Inside a scriptlet, you can write any code that would work in a normal Apps Script file: scriptlets can call functions defined in other code files, reference global variables, or use any of the Apps Script APIs. You can even define functions and variables within scriptlets, with the caveat that they can't be called by functions defined in code files or other templates.

So, you can create an HTML Template file (from the `File > New > HTML file` menu item in the Apps Script UI) and set it up ready to receive data from whatever your Apps script function processes.

#### Setting up your HTML:

As a simple example, you can create an HTML file called `emailTemplate.html` which contains the following data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hi <?!= name ?>, your email address is <?!= email ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your `Code.gs` file, you can load the data you want directly into your HTML template before evaluating it:

```js
var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate.html');

var clientname = spreadsheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
var clientemail = spreadsheet.getRange('P2').getValue();
  
htmlTemplate.email = clientemail;
htmlTemplate.name = clientname;
  
var emailBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate();
  
GmailApp.sendEmail(clientemail, 'subject', '', 
  {
    htmlBody: emailBody.getContent(),
  });
```

This mitigates any need to do replacing with `emailBody.replace({{NAME}}, clientname);` as the template is directly loaded with the variables that have been set in Apps Script.

For a person called `John Doe` with an email address of `john.doe@example.com`, the above example will send an email which will appear as:

```text
Hi John Doe, your email address is john.doe@example.com.
```

#### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: WOW, thanks for your super detailed answer. It's very helpful! Sadly, I now get the following error = TypeError: Cannot set property "clientname" of undefined to "clientname2". I tried to add .toString() but it didn't solve it :(

Comment: Which line is giving this error? Have you properly defined `spreadsheet`?

Comment: Yes. It's defined and also it shows the correct cell content inside the brackets for "clientname2".

Comment: htmlTemplate.name = clientname;

Comment: What is `clientname2`?

Comment: Apologies, I changed to clientname2 to avoid confusion, but it only created confusion :) This is the content of the cell in the spreadsheet. As said, the error does show the current content

Comment: What do you get when you log `clientname` and `clientemail`? `Looger.log("clientname = " + clientname + ", clientemail = " + clientemail);` ? Can you edit your question to include your whole code?

Comment: [20-06-10 12:15:17:513 IDT] clientname = nametest, clientemail = test@gmail.com

Comment: Hmm, I can't see what the issue could be as the script as-is works in my environment. Can you please share either your whole script, or, a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Had a stupid typo. Working perfectly now! You rock! Can I perhaps trouble you with some related issues? : 1. Logger = can I "save" these logs for later debugging? The executions log shows only errors and if no errors it's empty. 2. Can you recommend an easy HTML editor that can later be copied into the code file as an HTML doc? I've used MS-WORD but, needless to say, it sucks :) I saw some references here to using Google Docs and then coding an export to HTML but I couldn't get that to work :( Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help! As for Logger, use `console.log()` instead of `Logger.log()` and you can see them later in the execution transcript via the `View > Executions` menu item.

Comment: Stackoverflow rules actually say that software recommendations shouldn't be given, but the advice I'd give is that as far HTML editors go it's purely a matter of preference as there are many different ones out there. I'd suggest having a look around for different ones that suit your needs, if you're looking for simplicity then something like Notepad++ might be what you're after.